# Operand should contain 1 column(s) - in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following complex query that is giving me an error
   Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Can anyone suggest what is wrong

```
SELECT
t.user_id AS user_id,
t.organisation_id AS organisation_id,
t.firstname AS firstname,
t.surname AS surname,
t.username AS username,
t.year_id AS year_id,
t.form_name AS form_name,
t.House AS House,
rcPoints.total AS milestoneRedeemedCodesTotal,
rcFilteredPoints.total AS redeemedCodesTotalFiltered,
(
    COALESCE (rcFilteredPoints.total, 0) - COALESCE (milestoneHistory.total, 0)
) AS redeemedCodesTotalAvailableFiltered,
ABS(
    FLOOR(
        (
            COALESCE (rcFilteredPoints.total, 0) - COALESCE (milestoneHistory.total, 0)
        ) / 1000
    ) * 1000
) AS redeemedCodesTotalTowardsMilestone,
ABS(
    FLOOR(
        (
            COALESCE (rcFilteredPoints.total, 0) - COALESCE (milestoneHistory.total, 0)
        ) / 1000
    )
) AS redeemedCodesMilestoneTriggers,
COALESCE (milestoneHistory.total, 0) AS historyTotal
FROM
`myuser` `t`
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    rc.user_id AS user_id,
    SUM(rc.school_points) AS total
FROM
    `redeemed_codes` `rc`
INNER JOIN myuser m ON (m.user_id = rc.user_id)
WHERE
    (rc.date_redeemed >= 0)
AND (m.organisation_id = 58022)
GROUP BY
    rc.user_id
) AS rcPoints ON (rcPoints.user_id = t.user_id)
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    rc.user_id AS user_id,
    SUM(rc.school_points) AS total
FROM
    `redeemed_codes` `rc`
INNER JOIN myuser m ON (m.user_id = rc.user_id)
WHERE
    (rc.date_redeemed >= 0)
AND (m.organisation_id = 58022)
GROUP BY
    rc.user_id
) AS rcFilteredPoints ON (
 rcFilteredPoints.user_id = t.user_id
)
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    mh.user_id AS user_id,
    mh.milestone_id AS milestone_id,
    MAX(mh.points_when_triggered) AS total
FROM
    `milestone_history` `mh`
WHERE
    mh.milestone_id = 13
GROUP BY
    mh.user_id
) AS milestoneHistory ON (
milestoneHistory.user_id = t.user_id
)
WHERE
(
    (
        SELECT
            COALESCE (count(*), 0)
        FROM
            milestone_history mha
        WHERE
            mha.milestone_id = 13
        AND mha.user_id = t.user_id
    ) = 0
)
AND (t.organisation_id = 58022)

AND 
 ( 
 SELECT * FROM
redeemed_codes t1
WHERE
organisation_id = 1
AND
(
    SELECT
        sum(school_points)
    FROM
        redeemed_codes t2
    WHERE
        t2.redeemed_code_id <= t1.redeemed_code_id
) >= 1000
 ORDER BY redeemed_code_id
 LIMIT 1
)

GROUP BY
t.user_id
ORDER BY
redeemedCodesMilestoneTriggers DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You cannot simplify this problem?  You really wrote this entire query without testing any components, so the problem just appeared and you don't know where it is?  Test your queries as you write them, so you can find such problems easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your query might have multiple errors, but this condition in the `WHERE` clause is definitely suspect and would lead to that error:

```
AND  (SELECT *
      FROM redeemed_codes t1
      WHERE organisation_id = 1 AND
            (SELECT sum(school_points)
             FROM redeemed_codes t2
             WHERE t2.redeemed_code_id <= t1.redeemed_code_id
            ) >= 1000
      ORDER BY redeemed_code_id
      LIMIT 1
     )
```

I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Sometimes, the solution is simply `EXISTS`:

```
EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM redeemed_codes t1
        WHERE organisation_id = 1 AND
              (SELECT sum(school_points)
               FROM redeemed_codes t2
               WHERE t2.redeemed_code_id <= t1.redeemed_code_id
              ) >= 1000
       )
```